# Multiple attempts to update, delete and create the ADO.NET edmx file, and I still get "The entity type <company> is not found in the current context"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web app with a connection to a SQL Server database using Entity Framework. After removing three columns from the SQL Server database, I needed to update the web app to match. Starting in the dev branch I have tried multiple ways of updating the edmx file in the code.

I am at a loss as to options. Since the edmx file is changed/updated/re-created it breaks with the above error.

I have attempted the following steps:

1. Simply removing the fields from the designer and letting it save and populate through the other contexts and EF files
2. Updating the model from the database
3. Deleting and re-creating it from the ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard.
4. I have compared branches with git diff
5. I have checked and tested the connection string to verify it's not a mistake after the change.

**UPDATE**

With the possibility of previous residual files conflicting with the edmx file change, I attempted two possible options to remove any of those stale files:

In Azure Pipelines, I added Advanced Deployment Options with the RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag and ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag which did not resolve the issue.

I also tested deleting the directory files in the Azure DevOps repos and re-pushing to the pipelines, which also did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I assume you’re using EF6 - in which case you don’t need an EDMX file at all. You can use the “EF POCO T4” (on GitHub) to generate (and re-generate) code-first equivalents. It’s waaaaaaay better than EDMX.

Comment: Also, did you manually nuke your deployment directory before you published? There might be some old leftover files conflicting and breaking things.

Comment: Dai, I'll take a look into using POCO T4 as I've not worked with it before. Also, maybe I'm still too new to programming, but I've not sure what you mean by 'nuke your deployment directory'.

Comment: In Azure Pipelines, I added Advanced Deployment Options with the RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag and ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag which did not resolve the issue. I also tested deleting the directory files in the Azure DevOps repos and re-pushing to the pipelines, which also did not resolve the issue.